# Object references and typecasting in JAVA

Tags: java, casting, object-reference

Do I still work on the same object data after a typecast of the data?

A pseudo code sample could be:

```
MyClass car = new MyClass();
car.setColor(BLUE);

VW vw = (VW)car; //Expecting to get a blue VW.
vw.topSpeed = 220;

//Will car have the top speed set now? If topSpeed is a part of the Car object.
```

Comment: Are you trying to use JavaScript and a Java applet together, and you need to access objects from one another?

Or, did you just choose the wrong tag `javascript`, and you want to ask just a Java question?

Comment: Sorry, It isn't javascript. It is Java, I will fix the tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I still work on the same object data after a typecast of the data?

Yes. Casting changes the type of the reference you have to the object. It has no effect on the object itself at all.

Note that in your example, for the cast to be successful, `VW` would have to be a superclass of `MyClass` or an interface `MyClass` implements, e.g.:

```
class MyClass extends VW // or extends something that extends VW
```

or

```
class MyClass implements VW
```

Concrete example:

```
class Base {
    private int value;

    Base(int v) {
        this.value = v;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public void setValue(int v) {
        this.value = v;
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    Derived(int v) {
        super(v);
    }
}
```

Then:

```
Derived d = new Derived(1);
System.out.println(d.getValue());  // 1
Base b = d;                        // We don't need an explicit cast
b.setValue(2);                     // Set the value via `b`
System.out.println(d.getValue());  // 2 -- note we're getting via `d`
Derived d2 = (Derived)b;           // Explicit cast since we're going more specific;
                                   // would fail if `b` didn't refer to a Derived
                                   // instance (or an instance of something
                                   // deriving (extending) Derived)
d2.setValue(3);
System.out.println(d.getValue());  // 3 it's the same object
System.out.println(b.getValue());  // 3 we're just getting the value from
System.out.println(d2.getValue()); // 3 differently-typed references to it
```

Comment: Also, `topSpeed` must be accessable

Comment: So if I call `car.getTopSpeed()` at the end, I will get 220?

Comment: @FireFly3000: Yes, if `topSpeed` really is accessible where you've set it in your code. I added a concrete example using getters/setters (best practice).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Why doesn't your example work if I remove `d` from the code and initiates `Base b = new B(1);`? It comlains that B cannot be cast to the derived d.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder `B` will just be a default `B` object.

Comment: @FireFly3000: There is no default `B` object. In the example we have two classes (`Derived` and `Base`), and we have a `b` variable. We have nothing called `B`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94607/discussion-between-firefly3000-and-t-j-crowder).